# Forward declarated class with default value

Tags: c++, default-value, forward-declaration

I have a forward declaration but want to have a instatance of the forward declarated class as default value.

So my code looks more or less like this:

bar.h

```
class Foo;

class Bar
{
public:    
    Bar();
    void test(Foo foo = Foo(7));
}
```

and foo.h

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int val);
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: `test(Foo foo = 7);` what's that?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a method declaration? Then you forgot the return type

Comment: You are right. I edited it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible as described in another answer.

Apart of that, default values are the code smell. They make your interfaces fragile

Use method overloading instead:

```
class Foo;

class Bar
{
public:    
    Bar();
    void test();           // implement with default value, and document it
    void test(Foo foo);    // implement with user-supplied value
}
```

In `bar.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"   // Complete Foo is available here

void Bar::test()
{
    test(Foo(42));
}

void Bar::test(Foo foo)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did it this way. And this works fine. I just thought maybe there is a better (or shorter) way to do it, since I don't know all the fancy c++-stuff

Answer (score 2):

No. When you declare a method/function which argument is `Foo` the compiler should already know the size of `Foo`, so it should be already defined at that moment. If you declared but not defined `Foo` you may use only pointers or references to it.